# AttributeError: 'HttpxBinaryResponseContent' object has no attribute 'with_streaming_response'

Tags: python, openai-api

I am using openai to convert text into audio , how ever this error always pops up : AttributeError: 'HttpxBinaryResponseContent' object has no attribute 'with_streaming_response'
I have tried the `stream_to_field()` function but it neither works

```
def audio(prompt):

speech_file_path=Path('C:\\Users\\beni7\\Downloads\\proyectos_programacion\\proyecto_shorts\\audio').parent / "speech.mp3"
  response = openai.audio.speech.create(
  model="tts-1",
  voice="alloy",
  input=prompt
 )
 response.with_streaming_response.method(speech_file_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below approach:

```
def audio(prompt):
    speech_file_path = "speech.mp3"

    response = openai.Audio.create(
        model="tts-1",
        voice="alloy",
        prompt=prompt
    )

    with open(speech_file_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(response["audio"])

audio("Hello, this is a test.")
```

Answer (score 0):

.with_streaming_response is a method on speech. You can try the following:

```
def audio(prompt):
    speech_file_path="<file path>"
    with client.audio.speech.with_streaming_response.create(
        model="tts-1",
        voice="alloy",
        input=prompt,
    ) as response:
        response.stream_to_file(speech_file_path)
```